# I'm looking for a clone of Google Instant that dynamically changes the page as you continue to type (autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete, google-instant

I'm trying to find a tutorial or script that has most of the Google Instant functionality but I would be hit my API instead of Google and then displaying results from my domain.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an AJAX autocomplete. jQuery UI has a built-in [autocompleter](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) that's very easy to work with.

Comment: Note that the search (which is the actual core of the functionality) must be done by the backend, or a pre-defined array of results must be provided.

Comment: Yep. As he mentioned hitting his own API, I figured he has enough knowledge of that end of stuff.

Comment: I think he's talking about the feature on Google that changes the whole result page as you type, not the input's autocomplete.

Comment: I can get the auto complete to work I need to figure out how to change the results page based on the selected word in the autocomplete.

Comment: Can anyone help this problem?

Comment: I found this script using the Google custom search engine api and works great. I can modify this to my needs. http://www.rsc-ne-scotland.org.uk/mashe/2010/09/google-custom-instant/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial: http://woorkup.com/2010/09/13/how-to-create-your-own-instant-search/

You can also look at the source of the many available jQuery plugins for that purpose (google for "live search", "instant search" or similar). For instance, this one: http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/